# IE 8 disabled textbox issue

Tags: html, css

I have a disabled textbox, and i have applied the padding property to it and is working fine on every browser except IE8. Please see the below chrome image:

[image]

But in IE the same thing is shown as like:

[image]

**CSS Code:**

```
input[type=text]:disabled {    
    padding: 4px 9px !important;    
}
```

**Please suggest me something how to solve this issue.**

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes the please let me know what css should i apply to match the height, because i have tried everything and its does not seems to be working.

Comment: Check out [selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE8 does not support the `:disabled` pseudo-class (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:disabled#Browser_compatibility)).

Try using `input[disabled]` instead.

Comment: then what about mentioning the `type`, how to specify the type only as of `textbox`

Comment: You can stack those `input[type="text"][disabled]`